# how to parse values from text file and assign it for shell script arguments

Tags: shell, sh

I have stored some arguments value in sample.txt

```
1 >> sample.txt
2 >> sample.txt
3 >> sample.txt
```

I have tried to parse the sample.txt in a shell script file to collect and assign the values to specific variables.

```
   #!/bin/sh     
   if [ -f sample.txt ]; then

   cat sample.txt | while read Param

   do

   let count++
   if [ "${count}" == 1 ]; then

   Var1=`echo ${Param}`

   elif [ "${count}" == 2 ]; then

   Var2=`echo ${Param}`

   else

   Var3=`echo ${Param}`

   fi

   done

   fi


echo "$Var1"
echo "$Var2"
```

echo results prints nothing. I would expect 1 and 2 should be printed. Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the while loop in a subshell; use input redirection instead of `cat`:

```
while read Param; do
  ...
done < sample.txt
```

(Also, `Var1=$Param` is much simpler than `Var1=$(echo $Param)`.)

However, there's no point in use a `while` loop if you know ahead of time how many variables you are setting; just use the right number of `read` commands directly.

```
{ read Var1; read Var2; read Var3; } < sample.txt
```